# Angular material Stepper not work - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

Angular material [Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) not work Angular-6 , I following they are provided instructions but I face some conflict , got a lot of error
any one know how to fix that issue

Thanks

> GET
>   http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/46C70D82-2833-B24C-9A8E-E03849F5DBD7/main.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/ngx-bar-rating/themes/br-default-theme.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. compiler.js:2547 Uncaught
>   Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't
>   a known property of 'form'. ("-stepper labelPosition="bottom"
>   stepper>
>       
>         ][formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
>           Fill out your name
>       "): ng:///AppModule/BookingcalendarComponent.html@4:12 Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
>       
>       
>         ][formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
>           Fill out your address "): ng:///AppModule/BookingcalendarComponent.html@15:12
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
>       at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
>   (compiler.js:19495)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
>   (compiler.js:25041)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
>   (compiler.js:25028)
>       at compiler.js:24971
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   (compiler.js:24971)
>       at compiler.js:24881
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.js:24880)

**My code part,**
html

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" optional>
          <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
              <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step>
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
          You are now done.
          <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </mat-step>
      </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-Bookingcalendar',
  templateUrl: './Bookingcalendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Bookingcalendar.component.css']
})
export class BookingcalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ProjectOne</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/carousel.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/ngx-bar-rating/themes/br-default-theme.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is there in your `index.html` ?

Comment: Paste what's in your file `index.html`..

Comment: hello @selemmn , I Update my question , please check it .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module declaring `BookingcalendarComponent`, e.g.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @core114 where did you import the module? where did you declare your component?

Comment: Hello, I imported to `app.module.ts`

Comment: @core114 and in which module did you declare the `BookingcalendarComponent`?

Comment: @core114 what does the template like where you use the `<app-Bookingcalendar></app-Bookingcalendar>` component? You surely need to declare `BookingcalendarComponent` in one module, see https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodules-and-components

Comment: Yes I all ready declarer it, but not working, again will try it

Comment: @core114 in which module did you declare `BookingcalendarComponent `?

Comment: declared `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: I am still pretty sure that importing `ReactiveFormsModule` in the same module where you declare `BookingcalendarComponent` resolves your issue. it would be helpful to provide your complete code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: your solution work for me, im re added your code part and i do some little changes i added this `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'`;, now its work for me  ,Thanks